# Heroku app showing blank page, nothing useful in logs. Same code works fine on local

Tags: heroku

So I have a heroku app running at http://hidden-dusk-2939.herokuapp.com/

This app is just a wordpress site, and the exact same code works great on my local machine. However, if you navigate to that url, you'll find a blank page there.

```
 heroku logs
```

gives me this (which looks fine to me):

```
 2014-07-18T13:30:31.324343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hidden-dusk-2939.herokuapp.com request_id=80a4b066-4d0f-4e91-bc66-50750115846a fwd="165.215.94.11" dyno=web.1 connect=2 service=122 status=200 bytes=987
 2014-07-18T13:30:31.875110+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.6.103.177 - - [18/Jul/2014:13:30:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
```

The app appears to be running fine from the admin panel on heroku.com.

Is there anything else I can do to debug this? It was working fine when I last touched it yesterday, and then this morning it appears to be broken.

Both the local and and remote database have the same theme installed, although some of the data in the database (i.e. blog posts etc) are not identical.

Comment: Does wordpress still have the concept of a home url of sorts, that it relies on being configured? Is it possible you have that url configured to your local host?

Comment: I don't think so. Without configuring anything I was able to push the code to heroku and start using my live site no problem.

Comment: Any chance you have an empty index.html or index.php file that's being served, instead of Wordpress? Have you seen [this project](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku) for running Wordpress on Heroku?

Comment: That is exactly the project that I'm using!